# Why changing environments and OS made changes in data transfer in python flask and why did the fix I applied worked?

Tags: python, ubuntu, flask, centos

I had created a REST API in flask and had deployed it in an Azure server running CentOS 6.9 with Python default version 3.6.4. All I needed to import were the flask, cors packages to get everything up and running.

Now when I deployed the same on an AWS running Ubuntu 16.04.3 with Python default version being 2.7.12, problems started to occur.

The strings that flask received which were parameters for database queries had to be encoded to `UTF-8`; meanwhile, when arguments passed from the flask file to other imported modules(manually created), they were being received as `byte` data types and needed to be decoded to `UTF-8`. Along with this, I had to use the package future in all modules to get it to work. The imports from the future package are -

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from builtins import open
from builtins import str
```

I need to know what broke and why and how it got fixed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Probably you need to execute the `pasturize` script. Look at this [future module documentation](http://python-future.org/quickstart.html#to-convert-existing-python-3-code).

Answer (score 0):

These errors have occurred because of how Python syntax used to be in python 2 and how it is in python 3.
you should check the change logs or `whats new in python 3` to get the whole changes.

`print` function used to be a statement. so to `print`, you would have to do the following:

```
print "hello world" # python 2.7
print("hello world") # python 3.7
```

`string` objects were `Ascii` and you had a `Unicode` object. so if you wanted `Unicode` strings in `Python 2`, you had to convert them. now day's, the default is `Unicode` and `bytearray`, `byte` exists too.

you should check for the complete list of python 2 and 3.

`flask` on the other hand, is a package compatible with both `python 2` and `python 3`, so you didn't have any problem with `flask` codes, just `python 3` stuff that was not present in `python 2`.

Comment: I know about that, but I wanted to know how it worked and why is the same data when transferred between functions changing data types.